# Gas cost error in contract deploy

Tags: gas

Gas costs:
Gas requirement of function FarmToken.balance is infinite:
If the gas requirement of a function is higher than the block gas limit, it cannot be executed.
Please avoid loops in your functions or actions that modify large areas of storage
(this includes clearing or copying arrays in storage)

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/9b3710465583284b8c4c5d2245749246bb2e0094/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/9b3710465583284b8c4c5d2245749246bb2e0094/contracts/utils/Address.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/9b3710465583284b8c4c5d2245749246bb2e0094/contracts/token/ERC20/SafeERC20.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/9b3710465583284b8c4c5d2245749246bb2e0094/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract FarmToken is ERC20 {
    using Address for address;
    using SafeMath for uint256; // As of Solidity v0.8.0, mathematical operations can be done safely without the need for SafeMath
    using SafeERC20 for IERC20;

    IERC20 public token;

    constructor(address _token) public ERC20(){
        token = IERC20(_token);
    }

    function balance() public view returns (uint256) {
        return token.balanceOf(address(this));
    }

    function deposit(uint256 _amount) public {
        // Amount must be greater than zero
        require(_amount > 0, "amount cannot be 0");
    
        // Transfer MyToken to smart contract
        token.safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount);
    
        // Mint FarmToken to msg sender
        _mint(msg.sender, _amount);
    }
    
    function withdraw(uint256 _amount) public {
    // Burn FarmTokens from msg sender
    _burn(msg.sender, _amount);

    // Transfer MyTokens from this smart contract to msg sender
    token.safeTransfer(msg.sender, _amount);
    }
    
    function () external payable {}

}
```

Comment: Hi there! We'll need more information on this to be able to really help: the error means that there's likely an infinite loop somewhere in the code you're trying to deploy, so  you might want to post the contract contents here - you can create a formatted code block using three backtics: ```

Comment: Hi ! thanks!  please see the code of contract is the Ethereum.org farm contract example, i don´t understand why the error